# hiding an html element after showing for few seconds

Tags: javascript, jquery

After a successful ajax call I m showing an element telling the success status. I need to show it temporarily and hide it after say 10 seconds.

I have a paragraph element with the class set to hide on load `<p class="response hide" >Successfully Updated!</p>`

The code below does not seem to work as the element does not hide after its shown by adding the 'show' class

```
function UpdateChangeRequest() {
        $.ajax({
            url: '/Request/UpdateRequest',
            cache: false,
            data: $('form[id="RequestForm"]').serialize(),
            type: 'POST',
            success: function (data) {
                $('.divPartial').html(data);
                $('.response').addClass('show').removeClass('hide');                    
                setTimeout(function () {
                    $('.response').fadeOut('fast');
                }, 1000);
            }
        });
    }
```

Any ideas? thanks

Comment: Could you plese post your markup ? Thanks

Comment: can you please add your ajax call as well.

Comment: I tried throwing your code into codepen, and it works without any problem

Comment: Please see above and the mark up has the element ` <p class="response hide" >Successfully Updated!</p>`

Comment: If you want to make use of jquery.fadeIn/fadeOut, you should not bother playing around with those add remove classes. If it is the add-remove-class method that you want to use, you should define css transition in your css, so that toggling class is sufficient

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should try to make something like the below in your `success` callback:

```js
$(function(){
  $('.response').hide();
  
  $('#fake').click(function(){
    
      $('.response').show();
    
      setTimeout(function () { $('.response').fadeOut('fast'); }, 1000);
  });
                   
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p class="response" >Successfully Updated!</p>

<input type="button" value="click" id="fake"/>
```

**Update**

Since you updated you post, I could be more specific:

```
function UpdateChangeRequest() {
    $.ajax({
        url: '/Request/UpdateRequest',
        cache: false,
        data: $('form[id="RequestForm"]').serialize(),
        type: 'POST',
        success: function (data) {
            $('.divPartial').html(data);

            // Show the success message
            $('.response').show();

            // Define a timeout after which fade out the success message.  
            setTimeout(function () { $('.response').fadeOut('fast'); }, 1000);

        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

what about simple:

```
$(obj).show().delay(10000).hide();
```

Answer (score 0):

Find your element, show it, add a delay of 10 seconds, and finally hide it. You can chain all these effects/events like that:

```
$('.response').show().delay(10000).hide();
```

Comment: Can you add some context around why this is the correct answer?

Comment: Sorry mate, I don't get your question.

Comment: Generally code-only answers don't fly well and get flagged as such. A good code answer has some context that explains what's going on and why it solves the OP's question.

Answer (score 0):

You may use callbacks.

```
$(".response").fadeIn("slow","swing", function()
    {
        (".response").delay(10000).fadeOut("slow");
    });
```

http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_callback.asp

Answer (score 0):

You code should be working like i mentioned in the comments. I have put them in codepen with minimum changes

html:

```
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.2.min.js"></script>
<p class="response hide" >Successfully Updated!</p>
<!--- response msg is hidden by default --->
```

css:

```
.hide{
  display: none;
}
```

js:

```
var millisecondsToWait = 1000;

$(document).ready(function(){
    //$('.response').addClass('show').removeClass('hide');


    $('.response').show();
    setTimeout(function () {
      $('.response').fadeOut('fast');
    }, millisecondsToWait);
});
```

codepen example:  http://codepen.io/anon/pen/bNrGwW

Answer (score -1):

Try this :-

```
$('.response').show().delay(10000).fadeOut('slow');
```

Comment: Why `show` and `fadeOut` and not `fadeIn` and `hide`? Why `slow` and not `fast`? OP asked to show and hide. That's all. + it took you at least 3 edits to get there... hence my downvote.

Comment: @MrUpsidown: Ignore any edits up to the 4 minute mark... Vote based on the answer as it stands.